# Rails API ActiveStorage: Get Public URL to display image from AWS S3 Bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails 5.2 API set up and have followed the documentation on how to attach images to a model object - that's all working fine. The problem I'm having is I want to return in a JSON object the attachment's public URL so that I can use that URL as the source in an `<img src...` in my React front end. Is there a way to return the actual URL from the AWS S3 bucket, where the image would show up if clicked on?

Right now, I've tried `rails_blob_path`, `service_url`, and I do get URLs in return, but neither of them actually render the image the way I'd hope. Any workarounds to this?

Again, just want the attachment's actual public URL from s3 so I can plug it in to the `src` attribute inside an `<img>` and have it display. Thanks.

My development.rb file configures `config.active_stoarge.service = :amazon`.

My storage.yml file has amazon configured like so:
`amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.secrets.amazon[:access_key] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.secrets.amazon[:secret_key] %>
  region: us-east-2
  bucket: my_bucket_name_here`

ActiveStorage 5.2.2

Rails 5.2.2

Comment: what is `service_url` returning?

Comment: Can you post your configuration file for active storage and note which environment you're seeing this behavior in? Also, which exact version of activestorage & rails are you using (from Gemfile.lock)  `rails_blob_path` and `rails_blob_url` both work as expected in latest stable rails

Comment: Okay so I just got a direct link to the image on s3 with `service_url`. Am I right in assuming that link will never change, and always point to the image on s3 as long as it exists? @LeninRajRajasekaran @Jay Dorsey

Comment: I found one other potential solution for this. Try the `url_for` helper: `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(object.attachment)`

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use `rails_blob_url` or `rails_blob_path` to create a link to the actual file.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files

Comment: Those each return a relative path to the image within my app, and not an external link to the image at S3. I would like to find a way to see the direct image URL from S3 instead. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @tman091 is this in the local development environment? Or in a deployed application? If you followed a tutorial online you may have configured it to use `service: Disk` for local development which would store the images locally, rather than on S3. You can swap that to use the same production config (and add your env vars locally) to make it push to S3. If it's production, ensure your configuration is set for your environment to `service: s3`

Comment: These are good points Jay. It is in the local dev environment, but I configured my storage.yml to point at the s3 service instead of `disk` like you mentioned. I can confirm that everything is pushing up to s3 without any problems, so I know this is set up correctly.