# Errno::ENOENT in ActiveStorage::DiskController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

app/controllers/admin/home_controller.rb

```
class Admin::HomeController < Admin::BaseController
  def show
  end
end
```

app/views/admin/home/show.html.slim

```
    - if current_user.avatar.attached?
      / - binding.pry
      = image_tag current_user.avatar.variant(resize: "160x160"), alt: 'User Image', class: 'img-circle elevation-2'
    - else
      = image_tag 'backend/default-avatar.png', alt: 'User Image', class: 'img-circle elevation-2'
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

config/storage.yml

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

**I works in environment: developpment.
But it doesn't work in environment: production**

```
Errno::ENOENT in ActiveStorage::DiskController#show
No such file or directory @ rb_file_s_mtime - /apps/example.com/releases/20200129093910/storage/kD/vP/kDvP9igiNZ58NMWhx1zAiKoC
```

Rails 5.2.4

Used:

1. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-storage
2. [Active_Storage (Failed to load resource: 500 error) in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667216/active-storage-failed-to-load-resource-500-error-in-production?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31581
4. [Rails API ActiveStorage: Get Public URL to display image from AWS S3 Bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752070/rails-api-activestorage-get-public-url-to-display-image-from-aws-s3-bucket)

Comment: Do you have `storage` directory in your production server?

Comment: Yes, I have `/apps/example.com/current/storage` directory

Comment: And `/apps/example.com/releases/20200129093910` also?

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir public/storage
```

config/deploy.rb

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/uploads public/storage}
```

run command

```
bundle exec cap production linked_files:upload_dirs
```

Thanks [mechnicov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10608621/mechnicov).